# Ionic - installing push plugin gives error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to install push notification plugin for ionic app, by following this [docs](http://docs.ionic.io/v2.0.0-beta/docs/push-limited-setup), but I get an error when I run:

```
ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
```

The error:

> Error: Variable(s) missing (use: --variable SENDER_ID=value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mandatory `--variable SENDER_ID`. Do you have sender_id for Android? otherwise you can simply do:

```
ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXX"
```

if you have problems check the [doc](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md)